# What is the correct/best way to remove customizations from Microsoft Dynamics 365?

Tags: forms, axapta, x++, resource-cleanup, dynamics-365-operations

I've been experimenting with D365 in a virtual machine.
Not everything I've done has worked or has otherwise been desirable.
When I go to do other things, I sometimes can't save because of name conflicts.
Removing the directory for the models from C:\AOSService\PackageLocalDirectory did not resolve this, and in some context, I even have the possibility to add to the model which does not exist (which of course results in other errors).

Also, for example, when looking at a MainAccount's form, I still see fields which I previously created, despite having deleted both the model and the project...  Is there some way I can remove these?

Comment: Removing the model folder from the PackagesLocalDirectory should usually work. Make sure that the D365FO services are stopped during the removal. In some cases you might have to do a full compile of all models. Often times, instead of searching for the root cause of the issue, it can be more efficient to just set up a new clean VM.

Comment: @FH-Inway, cheers for the response.  What do I need to stop the services and to do a full compile?  I think I will probably go back to an earlier version of the VM as I have nothing valuable and it will probably be more efficient, but it would be good to know for the future.  :-)

Comment: To do a full compile, just select all models in the Visual Studio dialog where you do a model build. The services are listed in [Restart environment services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/lifecycle-services/restart-environment-services). On a local development vm, you need to stop the windows services (see [How to open Windows Services Manager and Manage Services using Command Line in Windows 10](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/open-windows-services) for a general introduction into Windows Service management).

Comment: @FH-Inway, Cheers for all the info!